# Get a value in a function with bit manipulation

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit

In a particular graphic library one represents pixels with 32-bit values consisting of four bytes for representing the four components
RED, GREEN, BLUE and Alpha.
The following definitions are available:

```
typedef unsigned int Uint32;
typedef unsigned char byte;
enum Color { RED = 0, GREEN = 1, BLUE = 2, ALPHA = 3 };
```

One now needs two free functions:

```
Byte getColorComponent (Uint32 pixel, Color color);
```

which, by means of bit manipulation, retrieves and returns the value of the one of the four color components shown in the color argument;
and

```
void setColorComponent (Uint32 & pixel, Byte value, Color color);
```

which takes stops in the Byte value in the right place (according to the color argument) in the pixel.

The answer is:

```
Byte getColorComponent(Uint32 pixel, Color color){   return (pixel >> (3-color)*8) & 0xFF; } 
void setColorComponent(Uint32& pixel, Byte value, Color color){   pixel &= ~(0xFF << (3-color) * 8);   pixel |= value << (3-color) * 8; }
```

I need help to understand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to help figure out this sort of problems, is to use ordinary pen and paper. Pick values for one or more variables, substitute them inside the expression. Continue substituting sub-expressions until there's a result.

Much like you simplify mathematical expressions.

For example with `getColorComponent`:

> Pick the color `GREEN` (with value `1`).
>
> Pick the pixel value `0x8a2be200` (which is an opaque blue-violet color, assuming [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space)).
>
> Original expression `(pixel >> (3 - color) * 8) & 0xff`
>
> Substitution chain
>
> 1. `(0x8a2be200 >> (3 - 1) * 8) & 0xff`
> 2. `(0x8a2be200 >> 2 * 8) & 0xff`
> 3. `(0x8a2be200 >> 16) & 0xff`
> 4. `0x8a2b & 0xff`
> 5. `0x2b`

With `color == GREEN` it extracts the `GREEN` color component of a 32-bit [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) color value.

If you use any of the other color enumeration values (`RED`, `BLUE` or `ALPHA`) doing the same thing, you will see that it extracts those components from the RGBA color value as well.

I leave it as an exercise for the readers to use this technique to figure out what `setColorComponent` is doing.

---

As an alternative, to use with computers and debuggers, split up a complicated expression into its smallest sub-expressions, assigning the results to temporary variables. Then use a debugger to step through the code line by line, to see the results come together.

With this the expression `(pixel >> (3 - color) * 8) & 0xff` would become the statements

```
auto t1 = 3 - color;     // 3 - color
auto t2 = t1 * 8;        // (3 - color) * 8
auto t3 = pixel >> t2;   // pixel >> (3 - color) * 8
auto t4 = t3 & 0xff;     // (pixel >> (3 - color) * 8) &0xff
```